# Lombok not compiling in maven

Tags: java, maven, lombok

I am trying to compile my project that uses lombok through maven and i am getting the following issue:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building akka-calculator-lib 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ akka-calculator-lib ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\dev\projects\Akka\akka-testing\akka-calculator\akka-calculator-lib\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ akka-calculator-lib ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ akka-calculator-lib ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 11 source files to C:\dev\projects\Akka\akka-testing\akka-calculator\akka-calculator-lib\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] \dev\projects\Akka\akka-testing\akka-calculator\akka-calculator-lib\src\main\java\com\mangusbrother\akka\calculator\lib\operation\multiply\MultiplyResult.java:[13,22] error: variable firstNumber not initialized in the default constructor
[ERROR] \dev\projects\Akka\akka-testing\akka-calculator\akka-calculator-lib\src\main\java\com\mangusbrother\akka\calculator\lib\operation\multiply\MultiplyResult.java:[14,22] error: variable secondNumber not initialized in the default constructor
[ERROR] \dev\projects\Akka\akka-testing\akka-calculator\akka-calculator-lib\src\main\java\com\mangusbrother\akka\calculator\lib\operation\multiply\MultiplyResult.java:[15,22] error: variable result not initialized in the default constructor
[ERROR] \dev\projects\Akka\akka-testing\akka-calculator\akka-calculator-lib\src\main\java\com\mangusbrother\akka\calculator\lib\CalculatorActor.java:[35,52] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \dev\projects\Akka\akka-testing\akka-calculator\akka-calculator-lib\src\main\java\com\mangusbrother\akka\calculator\lib\CalculatorActor.java:[35,87] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \dev\projects\Akka\akka-testing\akka-calculator\akka-calculator-lib\src\main\java\com\mangusbrother\akka\calculator\lib\CalculatorActor.java:[36,54] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \dev\projects\Akka\akka-testing\akka-calculator\akka-calculator-lib\src\main\java\com\mangusbrother\akka\calculator\lib\CalculatorActor.java:[37,74] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \dev\projects\Akka\akka-testing\akka-calculator\akka-calculator-lib\src\main\java\com\mangusbrother\akka\calculator\lib\CalculatorActor.java:[38,74] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \dev\projects\Akka\akka-testing\akka-calculator\akka-calculator-lib\src\main\java\com\mangusbrother\akka\calculator\lib\CalculatorActor.java:[38,101] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \dev\projects\Akka\akka-testing\akka-calculator\akka-calculator-lib\src\main\java\com\mangusbrother\akka\calculator\lib\CalculatorActor.java:[43,50] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \dev\projects\Akka\akka-testing\akka-calculator\akka-calculator-lib\src\main\java\com\mangusbrother\akka\calculator\lib\CalculatorActor.java:[43,85] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \dev\projects\Akka\akka-testing\akka-calculator\akka-calculator-lib\src\main\java\com\mangusbrother\akka\calculator\lib\CalculatorActor.java:[44,64] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \dev\projects\Akka\akka-testing\akka-calculator\akka-calculator-lib\src\main\java\com\mangusbrother\akka\calculator\lib\CalculatorActor.java:[45,84] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \dev\projects\Akka\akka-testing\akka-calculator\akka-calculator-lib\src\main\java\com\mangusbrother\akka\calculator\lib\CalculatorActor.java:[46,84] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \dev\projects\Akka\akka-testing\akka-calculator\akka-calculator-lib\src\main\java\com\mangusbrother\akka\calculator\lib\CalculatorActor.java:[46,111] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \dev\projects\Akka\akka-testing\akka-calculator\akka-calculator-lib\src\main\java\com\mangusbrother\akka\calculator\lib\CalculatorActor.java:[51,50] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \dev\projects\Akka\akka-testing\akka-calculator\akka-calculator-lib\src\main\java\com\mangusbrother\akka\calculator\lib\CalculatorActor.java:[51,85] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \dev\projects\Akka\akka-testing\akka-calculator\akka-calculator-lib\src\main\java\com\mangusbrother\akka\calculator\lib\CalculatorActor.java:[52,64] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \dev\projects\Akka\akka-testing\akka-calculator\akka-calculator-lib\src\main\java\com\mangusbrother\akka\calculator\lib\CalculatorActor.java:[53,84] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \dev\projects\Akka\akka-testing\akka-calculator\akka-calculator-lib\src\main\java\com\mangusbrother\akka\calculator\lib\CalculatorActor.java:[54,84] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \dev\projects\Akka\akka-testing\akka-calculator\akka-calculator-lib\src\main\java\com\mangusbrother\akka\calculator\lib\CalculatorActor.java:[54,111] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \dev\projects\Akka\akka-testing\akka-calculator\akka-calculator-lib\src\main\java\com\mangusbrother\akka\calculator\lib\CalculatorActor.java:[59,50] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \dev\projects\Akka\akka-testing\akka-calculator\akka-calculator-lib\src\main\java\com\mangusbrother\akka\calculator\lib\CalculatorActor.java:[59,85] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \dev\projects\Akka\akka-testing\akka-calculator\akka-calculator-lib\src\main\java\com\mangusbrother\akka\calculator\lib\CalculatorActor.java:[60,60] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \dev\projects\Akka\akka-testing\akka-calculator\akka-calculator-lib\src\main\java\com\mangusbrother\akka\calculator\lib\CalculatorActor.java:[61,80] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \dev\projects\Akka\akka-testing\akka-calculator\akka-calculator-lib\src\main\java\com\mangusbrother\akka\calculator\lib\CalculatorActor.java:[62,89] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \dev\projects\Akka\akka-testing\akka-calculator\akka-calculator-lib\src\main\java\com\mangusbrother\akka\calculator\lib\CalculatorActor.java:[62,127] error: cannot find symbol
[INFO] 27 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] akka-parent ........................................ SUCCESS [  0.164 s]
[INFO] akka-testing ....................................... SUCCESS [  0.011 s]
[INFO] akka-calculator .................................... SUCCESS [  0.010 s]
[INFO] akka-calculator-lib ................................ FAILURE [  2.758 s]
[INFO] akka-calculator-creation ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] akka-calculator-lookup ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.120 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-02-14T19:01:21+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/169M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Where the first error type is for the fields in this class:

```
package com.mangusbrother.akka.calculator.lib.operation.multiply;


import com.mangusbrother.akka.calculator.lib.operation.MathematicalResult;
import lombok.Data;

/**
 * Created by Mangusbrother on 14/02/2016.
 */
@Data
public class MultiplyResult implements MathematicalResult {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 738641818941986L;
    private final int firstNumber;
    private final int secondNumber;
    private final int result;
}
```

and the second error is when a class tries to access getters from lombok classes

My maven pom.xml has the following in it:

```
<properties>
    <lombok.version>1.16.6</lombok.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Where are the souces located? `src/main/java`, `src/main/lombok`?

Comment: java. Do they have to be under lombok?

Comment: Yes. Try to move them.

Comment: It doesn't compile them under `src/main/lombok` so it's not working

Comment: How did you ran Maven? And what's the error? You should run `mvn clean package`.

Comment: @Tunaki no, nope! The source's are good at `/src/main/java`.

Comment: I ran `mvn clean install` . `mvn clean package` would give the same error

Comment: the lombok dependency should be "provided", see https://projectlombok.org/mavenrepo/. Can we see your maven output?

Comment: default scope is more inclusive than `provided` so it doesn't make a difference. Adding more detailed output to question

Comment: Your code works fine here (see http://i63.tinypic.com/33dlicw.jpg, I used an empty interface for MathematicalResult)

Comment: my interface is empty apart from extending Serializable

Comment: Do you have `lombok-maven` as your parent POM?

Comment: No. I'd rather not have a 3rd party parent pom either. I have seen other projects work without it as a parent too. so i'm sure it's not required

Comment: I don't know why but you got compiler error because of maven-compiler-plugin. If you can please change plugin version to 3.5 and check if it will work.

Comment: Yes this seems to have solved it for some reason...  Post as an answer please :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't know why but you got compiler error because of maven-compiler-plugin. If you can please change plugin version to 3.5 and check if it will work.

Comment: This was the issue. The above given configuration with the compiler plugin upgraded to 3.5.1 will let you use lombok without having to move anything from src/main/java or add extra plugins or inherit external parents

Comment: my maven-compiler-plugin is 3.8.1 and i'm still getting this error.

Answer (score 59):

Add `annotationProcessorPaths` to your maven-compiler-plugins configurations:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
  <configuration>
    <annotationProcessorPaths>
      <path>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>     
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
      </path>
    </annotationProcessorPaths>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: please put helpful comments about your answer

Comment: With maven compiler 3.6.x use "annotationProcessorPaths", works fine.

Comment: Thanks @RenatoGarcia, this was the right answer to me using Java 8 and maven compiler 3.6.2!

Comment: Adding lombok path to annotationProcessorPaths worked for me as well

Comment: This one does the trick. I've tried over many answers about enable Annotation processor but they are not enough to make it work. This should be the answer!

Answer (score 8):

My working configuration is as below.

In the pom file:

```
     <properties>
        <java.version>14</java.version>
        <lombok-version>1.18.12</lombok-version>
    </properties>

     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok-version}</version>            
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>14</source>
                    <target>14</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok-version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>                 
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Maven compiler plugin version 3.8.1 is significant here as the older version didn't work for me.

In the module-info.java

```
 requires static lombok;
```

Comment: This one worked for me. Before this when inspecting the generated class files the lombok methods were missing

Answer (score 7):

I struggled mightily with this and concluded that **Lombok 1.16+** and **Java 8** are a problem with earlier versions of Maven's compiler plugin. IDEA 2017.1 was building the code without errors, but Maven was throwing 'symbol not found' errors on public methods that were definitely there in a decompiled jar file.

By upgrading to **maven-compiler-plugin 3.6.1** across my project and its libraries I was able to get it resolved without having to go down the Delombok path, which I really wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

First you should locate your lombok source (java annotated with lombok) into `src/main/lombok` and add the [lombok-maven-plugin](http://awhitford.github.io/lombok.maven/lombok-maven-plugin/usage.html) to your project like this:

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.16.6.1</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>generate-sources</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>delombok</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

If you don't like to use the lombok-maven-plugin you need to add the following:

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.6</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

If you really like to put your lomboked source into `src/main/java` instead of the default `/src/main/lombok` [you have to go this way](http://awhitford.github.io/lombok.maven/lombok-maven-plugin/faq.html) which is not recommended:

```xml
<build>
  <sourceDirectory>target/generated-sources/delombok</sourceDirectory>
  <testSourceDirectory>target/generated-test-sources/delombok</testSourceDirectory>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.6.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>delombok</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>delombok</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <addOutputDirectory>false</addOutputDirectory>
          <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>test-delombok</id>
        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>testDelombok</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <addOutputDirectory>false</addOutputDirectory>
          <sourceDirectory>src/test/java</sourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</build>
```

Comment: You use the delombok plugin if you want to generate de-lombok'ed sources though no? I don't need expanded sources. I have the dependency already and the files are still not compiling

Comment: there is no *"**de**lombok plugin"*.

Comment: I don't use a delombok plugin only the goal of it See here: http://awhitford.github.io/lombok.maven/lombok-maven-plugin/usage.html

Answer (score 1):

Although the OP's problem appears to have been solved these symptoms can also be caused by this:

If Lombok is working in your IDE but behaving like its not generating any methods etc in the Maven build a cause of this can be that Maven has been set to use a different compiler to the javac compiler, which may have different instructions.

For example if your POM (or parent POM) contains something like this:

```
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerId>eclipse</compilerId>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```

In that case the eclipse compiler is being used, this compiler is much less lombok friendly and [has special instructions](https://projectlombok.org/setup/ecj).

[For my case that was bending the build process too out of shape and we decided not to use lombok as a result, sadly]

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to check what version of java is there in path . My issue was with Java 1.8 & 3.5 version . To get it working I had to switch to 1.7 & 3.5 . Please note we are still on 1.7

Answer (score 0):

Increase the stack size of the JVM using this argument: `-Xss10240m`

## MAVEN_OPTS

`set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xss10240m"` or `export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xss10240m"`.

## _JAVA_OPTIONS

`_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xss10240m"`.

## maven-compiler-plugin

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-Xss10240m</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

## spring-boot-maven-plugin

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <jvmArguments>
            -Xss10240m
        </jvmArguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```